# Power management issue?

Tags: wireless, power-management, overheating, hp-pavilion

am new on ubuntu yesterday i installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Pavilion g6 notebook PC with intel cote i7-3612 CPU and 4 GB Ram and am facing many problem and i can't solve any of them.
- Wireless Signal is too low.
-the laptop is always over heated (HP CoolSense is not working and i guess this will harm my HP)
- the battery get empty very fast (+3:30 hours on windows , 1:20 hour on ubuntu)

i've read many threads that talk about this issue and i tried to use the commands they recommended but it didn't work with me. i hope you can help me with these issues and it would be great if there was a step by step solution because am a first time user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i tried to use the commands they recommended but it didn't work with me" if you do not provide us with the commands all you might get as answers are these commands ;)

Comment: for example sudo iwconfig power off

Comment: Have a look @MutazalHawash http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: @Qasim am still new and the commands are still not familiar to me but i'll give it a try ! thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laptop-mode-tools from the Ubuntu Software Center works fine and it is easy to use, but it doesn't produce such a big improvement in battery life. Also you mentioned that you've got an overheating problem, so you probably want to take a look at a stronger alternative to laptop-mode-tools: TLP. This answer: [Improve Power Usage / Battery Life In Linux With TLP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter) is a great introduction to TLP. It will also give you an idea of how complicated it is to install and configure it. TLP is not in the Ubuntu Software Center, you have to add the PPA for TLP to your Software Sources in the Ubuntu Software Center.

I'm sorry that this answer is so low on details, but the answer I referred to above has got all the details for TLP. Also I'm warning you again that TLP can be hard to configure. Finally I suggest that you try rotating your laptop when it is placed on top of a table to find which way it is facing when it gets the strongest wireless signal.

Comment: thanks every body i solved the problem using the solution provided by @Qasim in the comments. <br /> http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681